# Java Regex for extracting price information

Tags: java, regex

I need some help in java regex. I have kind of below String from which I need to extract information

```
“some information text followed by some price detail like below

Amount: $45.75
Tax: $3.25
Discount: -$5.00
Total : *$49.00*

followed by some other information text”
```

I need regex to extract all the price (key,value) pairs like (`Amount`,`$45.75`), (`Tax`,`$3.25`)

Or maybe regex to extract price for a supplied key. i.e. `String amountregex = “regexstring”` should give `$45.75`

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to extract the data that you are looking for by repeatedly searching for this expression:

```
(Amount|Tax):\s+[$](\d+[.]\d\d)
```

You would need to properly escape this expression for use as Java literal.

The expression would produce two capturing groups when matched:

- Group 1 would be either `"Amount"` or `"Tax"`
- Group 2 would be the string representing the corresponding value.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/2XCrdO)

Comment: fantastic. thanks a lot for responding in a short time with exact answer+demo.